# Understanding complex pointer and address-of operators using *&*&p in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers, addressof

Can any one explain how the printf is printing hello in the following?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
 char *p;
 p="hello";
 printf("%s",*&*&p);
}
```

I know that *&p...means value in p, i.e the address of string "hello".  What is happening in the initial *&

Comment: `*&`, first taking the address and then dereferencing is the identity, so `*&*&p` is just `p`.

Comment: one doubt...assume p's address is 200 and "hello" starting address is 100...so *&*&p---*&*200---*&100....now what does &100 will give ....usually &p means address of the variable p....and how will it work for &100.... Thanx for the reply

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way. You can only take the address of lvalues, so `&100` is meaningless. `&p` gives you a `char**`, pointing to `p`. Dereferencing that, `*&p` gives you the object `&p` points to, namely `p`.

Answer (score 7):

As you said, `*&p` means `p`, that means the consecutive `*` and `&` cancels out. Hence `*&*&p` becomes `p` too.

And as @Kerrek said (in the comment) that `*&p` produces an lvalue, so you take its address *again*.

---

Note that your code is not standard conformant. `main()` must have `int` as return type. And you cannot assign `"hello"` to a *non-const* `char*`. It must be `const char*`. A standard conformant code would be this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   const char *p = "hello"; 
   printf("%s",*&*&p);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that `*&p` is an lvalue, so you can take its address again...

Comment: Cheers. I was just thinking that someone might come and ask why `**&&` doesn't work :-)

Comment: "And you cannot assign "hello" to a non-const `char*`. It must be `const char*`." Perhaps it's worth pointing out that C and C++ differ here. In C, the type of `"hello"` is `char[6]`, and assigning it to a `char*` is perfectly legal (since trying to modify string literals is undefined behaviour, it's usually a good idea to only assign them to `const char*`s also in C, though).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Is it `char[6]` or `const char[6]`?

Comment: In C, it's `char[6]`, in C++ it's `const char[6]`.

Answer (score 1):

`&p` is the address of `p`.

`*p` is the thing pointed at by the address `p`.

`*&p` is `*(&p)` the thing pointed at by the address `&p` - which is `p` itself (i.e., the thing pointed at by the address "address of p").

Thus it turns out that `*&p` is just `p` - the `*&` cancel each other out. You can repeat this: `*&*&p` will still be `p`. You can do this ad infinitum: `*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&p` will also be `p`.

Answer (score 0):

'*&' cancels each other. You are getting the address of p then dereferencing it again. So the end result will just be p.